# Import CentOS 7.7 iso image into LXD

Tags: lxd

How to import a specific CentOS 7.7-1908 ISO image into LXD cluster running on Ubuntu 20.04 host, and build a CentOS VM ?

Comment: See https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/creating-a-vm-from-iso/12762

Answer (score 0):

There is already a Centos7 virtual machine in the default images: server for LXD.

```
lxc launch images:centos/7 --vm Seven
```

However if you want to boot a LXD virtual machine from a ISO image follow this guide.

[Install Any OS via ISO in VM](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/install-any-os-via-iso-in-a-virtual-machine-vm/9281)